# vba, copy data from sparse column to form a new dense column

Tags: excel, vba, range

An over-simplified description of my problem is illustrated in the figures below. I want to transform sparse data from a column in the Page1 worksheet to dense and then load it in a dense range in the Page2 worksheet.

My solution so far is that in the following code snippet. I would like to know if there is a more efficient alternative to achieve this goal, namely without a for loop or at least without the j variable.

```
Sub CopyFromMultipleRanges()

With Worksheets("Page1")

.Range("A1:A5").Value = 1

.Range("A8:A10").Value = 2

Dim c_cell As Range
Dim j As Long

j = 1
For Each c_cell In .Range("A1:A5,A8:A10")
    Worksheets("Page2").Range("A" & j).Value = c_cell.Value
    j = j + 1
Next

End With

Worksheets("Page2").Activate

End Sub
```

[Initial column where data is sparse.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkX7q.png)

[Final dense data column.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiJx8.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this if  you want to remove the blanks on the same sheet. If not just copy the data to a new sheet and then run this on that range

```
Sub Delete_Blank_Rows()

On Error Resume Next
Range("A1:A10").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you need `.Select` or can you just use `Range("A1:A10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete`?

Comment: In the actual case not all the cells between the two sparse ranges are empty. More specifically these two ranges are identified within a loop when a certain condition is fulfilled. Then the two, or even more, sparse ranges have to be loaded to a different sheet in dense form.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it:

```
'create a collection to store the data
Dim bin As New Collection
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim size As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim v As Variant

'set worksheet references
Set ws1 = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Page1")
Set ws2 = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Page2")

With ws1
    size = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

    'loop through the range to pick up the data from non-empty cells
    For i = 1 To size
        'if the cell is not empty, then add the value to the collection
        If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
            bin.Add .Cells(i, 1).Value
        End If 
    Next

    'loop through the bin contents
    i = 1
    For Each v In bin
        ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value = v
        i = i + 1
    Next
End With
```

Hope it helps!

**Update:**

I tested this code and it works:

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set ws2 = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

    ws1.Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy ws2.Range("A:A")
End Sub
```

you can read more about Range.SpecialCells [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-specialcells-method-excel). learn something new everyday!

Comment: This code certainly works fine, provided that you increment i in the second loop. It is a nice alternative using Collection and Variant, however the idea is almost the same to that in my script. I am mostly interested to know if this can be done in fewer lines of code or at least without using the variable j.

Comment: But that would require reading; kidding of course.

I'm not entirely sure if there's a way to get past looping through the range because I'm unsure of the location of blank cells. If they were always in the same place at all times, then you could maybe just delete specific rows and that would condense the data for you. I'll do some research and let you know what I come up with.

Comment: @gva Why don't you want there to be loops? I'm just curious.

Comment: @gva I found a method that works without loops and updated my answer.

Comment: I am actually new to vba and since I am aware that there are many convenient ways to automatiza tasks like that in one or two lines of vba code, I want to learn how to write vba code efficiently. 
For the updated code I get your point but again my actual problem is how to copy two specific range not how to remove empty cells in between, since in the real case these cells are not all goning to be empty.

Comment: The updated answer does not delete empty cells, it selects the range and copies only the cells with content inside, so even if there are empty cells in the range, it ignores empty cells and only copies the cells with values inside.

My answer is similar to @VBA_SQL_PROGRAMMER, but it does not have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that you are considering the all rows with the lower and upper row limits of the ranges given ie. that "A1:A5" and "A8:A10" is indeed "A1:A10".

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CopyFromMultipleRanges()
    Dim rng As Range:  Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Page1").Range("A1:A10")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(rng) = rng.Count Then Exit Sub
    With rng
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter 1, "<>"
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Worksheets("Page2").Range("A1")
        .AutoFilter
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```